# append values to a empty list in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the below dataframe, column c will always have an empty list in it. I need to compute few things and add it to the list, for example append values of column a and b to the empty list of column c

Given df

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for this.

something like:

```py
df["Mark list"] = df.apply(lambda row: [row["Mark1"], row["Mark2"]], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!, one more question. If I have to append mark3 to the mark list how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```py
df["Mark list"] = df.filter(regex='Mark\d+').agg(list, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the columns you want to append into lists (using a custom function and apply) and then simply add them to the list column. This will work for columns calculated on the fly as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df_vals = {"mark1": [23, 34, 45], "mark2": [45, 34, 12], "mark_list": [[] for i in range(3)]}

to_list = lambda x: [x]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_vals)
df["mark_list"] += df["mark1"].apply(to_list)
df["mark_list"] += df["mark2"].apply(to_list)
df["mark_list"] += (df["mark2"] + df["mark1"]).apply(to_list)  # works for columns created on-the-fly
df
```

Output:

```
   mark1  mark2     mark_list
0     23     45  [23, 45, 68]
1     34     34  [34, 34, 68]
2     45     12  [45, 12, 57]
```